# Calculate $\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{1}{(1+\|x\|_2^n)^2}dx$

Tags: integration

How can I calculate the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{1}{(1+\|x\|_2^n)^2}dx
$$? Is there a "simple" way?

Comment: Spherical Coordinates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $r=\|x\|_2$ the integral becomes
\begin{align}
\int_{ \mathbb R^n }\frac{1}{ (1+\|x\|_2^n)^2 }dx 
&= \int_\Omega\int_{r=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(1+r^n)^2}r^{n-1} dr d\Omega \\
&= \Omega\int_{r=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(1+r^n)^2}r^{n-1}dr \\
&= \Omega\left( \frac{-1/n}{1 + r^n} \right)\Bigg|_{r=0}^\infty \\
&= \frac{\Omega}{n}
\end{align}
where volume form is written as $dx = r^{n-1} dr d \Omega$, and $\Omega$ is the total solid angle in $\mathbb R^n$ and $d\Omega$ is its differential element. I don't remeber what this  $\Omega$ is but you can find it in Wiki.